# Renaming object keys which are nested

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am accessing JSON which looks like this.

```json
[
{
    "itemType": "SelectionTitle",
    "_id": "5ada2217c114ca048e1db9b0",
    "created_by": "5ab57289d8d00507b29a3fdd",
    "selectionFile": {
        "item.Type": "SelectionFile",
        "name": "1105F.MID",
        "active": true,
        "isFactory.Default": false,
        "selection.Type": "Music",
        "sfzFile": "",
        "destination": "/data/uploads",
        "encoding": "7bit",
        "fieldname": "file",
        "filename": "782f49a7cd72b865b4e2d286816792e7"
        ...
      }
}, ...
```

And I am having trouble renaming the object keys which have the `.` in the name to an `_`. For example:

`item.Type` or `selection.Type` to `item_Type` or `selection_Type`.

This is what I am trying to use:

```
var json = jsonFromExampleAbove;
str = JSON.stringify(json);
str = str.selectionFile.replace(/\".\":/g, "\"_\":");
json = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(json);
```

I am getting a console log error. I think it is because the values I am trying to replace are nested, but not sure. I am still very much a beginner here.

Thank you.

Comment: `str.selectionFile.` you turned your object into a string of JSON text, there is no `selectionFile` property on strings. Also your regex is wrong, it is searching for `".":` which none of your keys have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to do it with a bit of recursion using `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const input = [
{
    "itemType": "SelectionTitle",
    "_id": "5ada2217c114ca048e1db9b0",
    "created_by": "5ab57289d8d00507b29a3fdd",
    "selectionFile": {
        "item.Type": "SelectionFile",
        "name": "1105F.MID",
        "active": true,
        "isFactory.Default": false,
        "selection.Type": "Music",
        "sfzFile": "",
        "destination": "/data/uploads",
        "encoding": "7bit",
        "fieldname": "file",
        "filename": "782f49a7cd72b865b4e2d286816792e7"
  }
}];

function replaceDots(obj){
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map( ([key,value]) => {
      const newKey = key.replace(".","_");
      return typeof value == "object"
        ? [newKey, replaceDots(value)]
        : [newKey, value]
  }));
}

const result = input.map(replaceDots);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive approach to replace the keys in the input object(s) with your desired result. There's no need to use JSON.stringify(), one can simply iterate through the objects.

We'll use `searchValue` to specify what we wish to search for and `newvalue` to specify the replacement, in this case they will be /./g and '_'.

```js
let arr = [
    {
        "itemType": "SelectionTitle",
        "_id": "5ada2217c114ca048e1db9b0",
        "created_by": "5ab57289d8d00507b29a3fdd",
        "selectionFile": {
            "item.Type": "SelectionFile",
            "name": "1105F.MID",
            "active": true,
            "isFactory.Default": false,
            "selection.Type": "Music",
            "sfzFile": "",
            "destination": "/data/uploads",
            "encoding": "7bit",
            "fieldname": "file",
            "filename": "782f49a7cd72b865b4e2d286816792e7"
          }
    }
]


function replaceKeys(obj, searchvalue, newvalue, newObj) {
    if (!newObj) newObj = Array.isArray(obj) ? []: {};
    for(let k in obj) {
        let newKey = k.replace(searchvalue, newvalue);
        if (typeof(obj[k]) === 'object') {
            newObj[newKey] = Array.isArray(obj[k]) ? []: {};
            replaceKeys(obj[k], searchvalue, newvalue, newObj[newKey])
        } else { 
            newObj[newKey] = obj[k];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}

const result = replaceKeys(arr, /\./g, '_');
console.log('Result:', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with a `replaceAll` on the stringified JSON could result in unwanted problems when a value contains a dot.

For renaming nested keys of an object you need go over the object recursively and assign the new keys while removing the old ones

```
// for ES6
function renameKey(obj) {
    // loop over all keys
    for (let k in obj) {
         // apply recursively if value is an object
         if (typeof obj[k] === "object" && obj[k] !== null)
             renameKey(obj[k]);
         // only replace keys of type String
         if (typeof k === 'string' || k instanceof String) {
             const newKey = k.replaceAll(".", "_");
             // assign {newKey:value} to object and delete old key
             delete Object.assign(obj, { [newKey]: obj[k] })[k];
         }
    }
    return obj
}
```